# How to make session variable last longer in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am storing a session variable in codeigniter but it lasts only for some time.  How to increase the time of sesion variable or make not expire in CodeIgniter?

Comment: It is set in `APPPATH . 'config/config.php'` [file](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php#L325).

Answer (score 1):

In your config config file, find this line $config['sess_expiration'] = 7200; and change it to whatever time you want.It is in seconds.